# Emulator hardware keyboard wrong mapping

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been using the Android Studio emulators for a while, but since a few days the mapping is broken. I have an azerty keyboard on my laptop, and when I type something, it appears as qwerty on the emulator (typing 'a' on the laptop will show 'q' on the emulator). Using the soft keyboard of the emulator works as expected, no matter if the soft keyboard is azerty or qwerty.

This issue appears on all emulators. I have tried to create a new emulator and cold booting. I can't seem to find a setting to change the mapping.

Is there a hidden setting or shortcut I can use to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the MEMU emulator

> [Memu Emulator](https://www.memuplay.com/)

Answer (score 0):

i have just had the same issue.
to solve it i proceeded this way :

1. in the android emulator in the menu Settings / general go to "send keyboard shortcuts to virtual device"

see the [android emulator config screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJJWJ.png)

2. i then installed an application "Clavier physique AZERTY." (see the link in this blog: [android-configurer-un-clavier-sans-fil-en-azerty](https://www.skyminds.net/android-configurer-un-clavier-sans-fil-en-azerty/))